# Exclude objects in query if certain value exists in serialized attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.1

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :pets, Array
end
```

How would I create a chainable query where I want to exclude users that e.g. has "cat" in the serialized `pets` attribute?

Comment: There's no **clean** way. When using serialization you lose most of the database's functionality, only persistence remains. You have to rely on what's "under the hood".

Answer (score 0):

```
User.where.not("pets = ?", ["cat"].to_yaml)
```

Comment: This will only work for exact matches (e.g. the user only has a cat), to get partial matches (e.g. they have a dog and cat, but still match), use `User.where("pets LIKE ?", "%#{['cat'].to_yaml}%")`